# Str Replace and Adding Space?

Tags: php

I used one solution to fix one problem, then when I went to fix another problem, it made the other problem occur again.

I'm currently using this to replace spaces with dashes.

```
$var2 = str_replace(' ', '-', $var2);
```

Now say `$var2` is an address, so 5019 Hill Street. I had it set to add a %20 to numerals so that it would say it as `5 0 1 9`. When I put the `str_replace` to add the dash, it screwed this up.

Is there a way to put within the string replace, both functions? I was using this to add the space between numerals.

```
if(is_numeric($var2)){
 $var2 = addSpaceToStr($var2);
}

function addSpaceToStr($str){
 $strLen = strlen($str);
 $strWithSpace = '';
 for($i = 0; $i <$strLen; $i++){
  $strWithSpace .= $str[$i];
  if(($i+1) != $strLen){
   $strWithSpace .= '%20';
  }
 }
 return $strWithSpace;
}
```

These are in two different files, so I tried different variations of putting them in just one file without success. As well as keeping them in separate files without success either. The first file curls over the variable with the dashes added, then the second file is suppose to add spaces to the numbers, but now it's not adding the spaces to the numbers. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your input and your expected output please. It's not so obvious at the moment.

Comment: Currently on submit it will submit 5019 Hill Street. The str_replace changes it to 5019-Hill-Street which is curled to api.php which then is suppose to add "%20" to numerals only. So api.php curls out to the last page it hits which should be 5%200%201%209-Hill-Street. Right now it's not adding the "%20" to the numbers, so when api.php curls to the last page, it sends 5019-Hill-Street

Comment: It looks like part of your `addSpaceToStr` function got cut off, could you paste the full thing? Also check out [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get your code section to appear mono-spaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding this,
`$var2 = preg_replace("/(\d)/", '$1 ', $var2);`
`$var2 = str_replace(' ', '-', $var2);`